# Sample integers from truncated geometric distribution

Tags: python, math

What is a good way to sample integers in the range {0,...,n-1} according to (a discrete version of) the exponential distribution?  `random.expovariate(lambd)` returns a real number  from 0 to positive infinity.

**Update.** Changed title to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is possible to sample from a distribution by generating a uniform random number then taking the inverse cumulative distribution (CDF).

So, to sample from the truncated distribution, you can generate a uniform random number, then take the inverse of the truncated CDF. The truncated CDF is just the normal CDF scaled by the value of the standard geometric CDF at `n-1`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p=.3

bins=np.arange(0,50,1)

r=np.random.rand( 1000 )
gen=np.floor(np.log(r)/np.log(1-p))
plt.hist(gen,bins=bins,alpha=.8)

N=5
gen_trunc=np.floor(np.log(1-r*(1-(1-p)**N))/np.log(1-p))
plt.hist(gen_trunc,bins=bins,alpha=.8)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this is obvious but how would I use this to give me individual integer samples in the desired range? It seems you have used plt.hist to discretise in your code if I understand correctly.

Comment: The samples should be the floor of `gen_trunc`.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete analogue of the exponential distribution is the [geometric distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricDistribution.html). This is implemented in [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.geometric(.01, 10)
array([ 33,  45,  41, 171,  62, 119,  56,  47,  30, 197])
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful.  I suppose to make it close to uniform you make p close to 1.

Comment: @marshall: yes. `p` represents the probability of a Bernoulli trial succeeding. When `p=1`, all trials succeed, so the output is an array of ones.

Comment: Oh.. this doesn't answer my question sadly. I want the values to be in the range 0 to n-1.  I would just like the probability of getting i+1 to be  c times the probability of getting i with 0 < c < 1.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: pick a random number from geometric distribution and return mod n.

Eg: random.geometric(p)%n

P(x) = p(1-p)^x+ p(1-p)^(x+n) + p(1-p)^(x+2n) ....

= p(1-p)^x *(1+(1-p)^n +(1-p)^(2n) ... )

Note that second part is a constant for a given p and n. The first part is geometric.

Comment: Is that provably correct? I mean what distribution does that give you?

Comment: This will give you exponential distribution. As in P(x+1) = (1-p) * P(x) where 0<=x<n

Comment: Thanks. I think it is still slightly off. Take p = 0.5 and n = 100. You are very unlikely to get 0 which should be the most likely outcome.

Comment: @marshall What!!! With p=0.5 p(1-p)^0 is equal to 0.5. So you should get half of random numbers to be 0.

Comment: np.random.geometric(0.5,100) gives no zeros.  I think it must be defined differently from what you expect. In general I think the geometric distribution is defined as the number of coin tosses until a success.

Comment: @marshall I don't have numpy installed on my machine, so I cannot test. I am pretty sure you are smart enough to take from here and achieve what you want. Good luck!